# Cant write to Firebase Database with Javascript on Glitch

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, glitch-framework

Im trying to create a simple app to add to a Firebase Database.

Write the temperature then store this in database with a timestamp. But for some reason it wont work. Ive tried multiple different ways and checked all the docs on the Firebase website but nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/lcjs

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.3.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <title>Write to firebase</title>
  </head>  
  <body>
    <h1>Current Tempature</h1>

    Tempature <input type="text" id="UserData"/>
    <input type="button" id="Submit" onclick="formSubmission()" value="Submit"/>

    <p id="done">
    </p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.JS

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDvLIcv7nEIbfnz99mhoLi8UizaJcZxHLM",
    authDomain: "lcls-332a0.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://lcls-332a0.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "lcls-332a0",
    storageBucket: "lcls-332a0.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "604417688851",
    appId: "1:604417688851:web:63eb89e29b81cd1a8546e6",
    measurementId: "G-N2TVNX43T6"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();

function formSubmission(){
  document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = "Clicked";
  var today = new Date();
  var timestamp = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds() + " " + today.getDate() + "/" + today.getMonth() + "/" + today.getFullYear();

  var myDBConn = firebase.database().ref();
  document.getElementById("done").innerHTML = "Done";
  var TempBranch = myDBConn.child("MyTempatures");

  var currentTemp = document.getElementbyID("UserData");

  TempBranch.push({ Tempature: parseInt[currentTemp.value], Time: timestamp });

  document.getElementById("done").innerHTML =
    "Your result has been successfully added!";
}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer based on what I see in your Glitch project. In future questions please always include the actual behavior that you get. It is much harder to help with "It doesn't work"  than with "I get 'document.getElementbyName is not a function'".

Answer (score 0):

When I run your Glitch project and submit a value, I see this error in the JavaScript console of Chrome:

> script.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementbyName is not a function
>
> at formSubmission (script.js:26)
>
> at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):11)

There is no method `document.getElementbyName`. You probably meant to use `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.getElementById`.

The same type of wrong method name is in the code in your question, where you have `getElementbyID`. You probably meant `document.getElementById` there too.

It's a good idea to pay close attention to spelling and uppercase/lowercase, as they are easy to overlook when you're reading the code, but make all the difference between working and non-working code.

Answer (score 0):

From Glitch.com support:

> "Hi there - so it looks like you started by remixing our React starter, which is a generated static site without a server - the server on the container is there for Vite to build the static files into the build folder which then gets deployed. Your app needs full-stack capability, though, for the database/api endpoints so this setup is not going to work for you.
>
> Because full stack apps with React front-ends and a database like MongoDB are a bit big (and often need multiple ports, which we don't provide) they're not a really good fit for a single Glitch app. You may want to try having one app for the generated static site and have it make API calls to another app that's full-stack with the database you want to use. Solutions for this would be a good thing to ask about in the Glitch forum - there may be some creators there that have gotten such a setup to work.
>
> Alternatively, if you're okay with not using React and just need any kind of database, we have a sqlite starter here: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/glitch-hello-sqlite?path=src%2Findex.jsx%3A1%3A0